# Is there any visibility and currents database/website for scuba divers?

Tags: online-resources, diving

I am looking for a database/website that allows looking up currents and visibility information for global (or at least Asian) dive sites.

To find this information without such a site is a true nightmare since one has to scour multiple forums and websites for a specific dive site, one by one. If I had a website with centralized information, I could much easier check where it is good to go during a specific week.

I want to be able to pick a dive site and find out how the situation is in a specific season instead of having to guesstimate the conditions by taking a national average or even having to ask in a forum if ever anyone has been to a place in a certain month and hoping for a reply...

Any one knows of such a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found some sites that give such information:

1. [worlddivingreview.com](http://www.worlddivingreview.com/) has a quite long list of one-page reviews per area, with lists of critters as well as best months to visit etc.
2. [divetime.com](http://www.divetime.com/) has a list per dive-site that has to be reviewed individually.
3. [myscubadives.com](http://myscubadives.com/) also has a list of dive sites where people can log their individual dives.

So the first site is probably the one to visit first for general information about a larger area, and then it would be good to scout the other 2 to find if someone actually logged a dive there.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at your certification and look at their website for various exploration projects.

For example. [GUE](http://www.globalunderwaterexplorers.org/exploration) has a list of current exploration projects with information on visibility from past dives.  Some [like Emerald Sink](http://www.globalunderwaterexplorers.org/projects/WKPP/updates/emerald-sink-feb-2013) have data more recent then others.

- [Scuba Adviser](http://www.scubadviser.com/Scuba-diving-destinations/-Destinations/South-East-Asia) also provides information on the dive sites in Asia but you will need to be a little more specific as to the dive site to get information.

Comment: Sorry, I must have asked wrong, since neither of this is what I searched for. Gue does not even list the country in the title of the list. This is for me more an insider's blog than a database. And Scuba Adviser lists 1 set of information for the whole country. I was looking for something where I can list observed dive sites per country, then region etc, and get info on dive sites. Or even take a month, chose a condition and then find places that match.